CORS Error for GET Request with Credentials in Django and React on Localhost Setup (Works with POST)
Introduction
I'm working on a Django backend with a React frontend, where I'm facing a CORS issue specifically for GET requests with credentials enabled. The POST requests work fine, but GET requests fail with a CORS error on the preflight request.
Setup and Background

Backend: Django with Django REST Framework and Simple JWT for authentication.

Frontend: React using axios with withCredentials: true.

Local Development:

Django is running locally and exposed using Ngrok (HTTPS).

React frontend is on a different machine running at 192.168.1.2:3000 or  localhost:3000.


I’ve configured django-cors-headers to manage CORS settings.


Problem

CORS Issue: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing in the response for GET requests, causing a CORS error.

Observations:

The POST request successfully attaches headers and completes.

The GET request triggers a preflight (OPTIONS) request, and the response from Django lacks the necessary CORS headers, leading to the error.




Code Samples

CORS Settings in settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  ...
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  ...
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
  "http://localhost:3000",
  "http://192.168.1.2:3000", # React frontend machine local ip
  "https://<ngrok_subdomain>.ngrok-free.app",
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ["Content-Type", "X-CSRFToken", "Set-Cookie"]  


Sample Django GET View:
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TestGetView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({"message": "GET works!"})


Axios Request in React:
axios.get('https://<ngrok_subdomain>.ngrok-free.app/test-get/', { withCredentials: true })
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));



Error Message
The following CORS error appears in Chrome and Safari (but it properly works in Opera):

Attempts to Fix

Verified CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS includes the correct domain.

Tried using CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False (also tried with True as a test).

Verified withCredentials: true is set in the axios request.

Ensured the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present in the POST response.


Question

Why would CORS work with POST but not with GET in this setup, especially when everything works in Opera?

Are there any configurations or additional middleware I need to handle CORS for preflight requests on GET for Chrome and Safari?



"The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing in the response for GET requests"... that's not what the error says
